# Geshi with Markdown

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, markdown, preg-replace-callback, geshi

Im trying to get GeSHi to work with markdown.

A simple use for Geshi is as follows:

```
$geshi = new GeSHi($message, 'c');
print $geshi->parse_code();
```

The above code takes in the whole of message and turns it into Highlighted code

I also have my Markdown Function

```
print Markdown($message);
```

I was trying to use call back function to `preg_match` the `<pre>` tags returned from markdown and run the `geshi->parse_code();` function on the returned values

Here is my code

```
print preg_replace_callback(
   '/<pre.*?>(.*?[<pre.*?>.*<\/pre>]*)<\/pre>/gism',
    create_function(
        // single quotes are essential here,
        // or alternative escape all $ as \$
        '$matches',
        '$geshi = new GeSHi($matches[0], \'php\'); return $geshi->parse_code()'
    ),
    Markdown($blog_res['message']));
```

Am i on the right track?

**Is My Regex right?** it works on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Thanks for the help

Comment: Does it work? If so I would say you are on the right track, if not, post what issues you are having for us to help you figure it out.

Comment: Well the issue is, its not working

Comment: it was the regex :(, instead of `/<pre.*?>(.*?[<pre.*?>.*<\/pre>]*)<\/pre>/gism` use `/<pre.*?>(.*?[<pre.*?>.*<\/pre>]*)<\/pre>/ism` remove the global flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the regex :(

instead of

```
/<pre.*?>(.*?[<pre.*?>.*<\/pre>]*)<\/pre>/gism
```

use (remove the global flag)

```
/<pre.*?>(.*?[<pre.*?>.*<\/pre>]*)<\/pre>/ism
```

But if you are using markdown, you have to remember to compensate for the `code` blocks that are on thier own therefore you need to replace only the ones that are in the format of `<pre><code>...MyCode</code></pre>` and leave out `Hello <code>MyCode</code>` Therefore you need the following

```
'/<pre.*?><code.*?>(.*?[<pre.*?><code.*?>.*<\/code><\/pre>]*)<\/code><\/pre>/ism',
```

Answer (score 3):

for future reference, you might want to check out my plugin for this:

https://github.com/drm/Markdown_Geshi

It is based on the regular markdown plugin adding a block marked with a shebang to highlight code, like this:

```
#!php
<?php print('This is PHP code'); ?>
```

Works pretty well and I use it on my own blog regularly.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you [were] looking to extend Markdown, adding support for GeSHi syntax highlighting. [Beautify](http://www.bitstorm.org/weblog/2012-8/Beautify_Markdown_SmartyPants_GeSHi_and_Dot_combined.html) does this and more. For example, it can render graphs in [DOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language).

Beautify's approach to GeSHi code blocks differs from [drm/Markdown_Geshi](https://github.com/drm/Markdown_Geshi) in that "fences" are used. For example:

```
~~~ php
<?php print('This is PHP code'); ?>
~~~
```

I'm not sure if Beautify was around back when this question was active, but it seemed worthy of mention in an answer.